# Object disappearing in animation timeline

Tags: animation, keyframes, grease-pencil, timeline

I’m extremely new to blender and following along a grease pen tutorial, it was going well but when I’m in the animation workspace my object disappears on the timeline after about 20 keyframes while in the tutorial he is able to move the timeline to 125 without the object disappearing.

The tutorial I’m following didn’t change or add anything to my knowledge to extend it, and I’m not sure if I’m getting terminology wrong as nothing comes up when googling it so I’m just stuck wondering what went wrong. I attached the [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nZyB30-xZFs) (time stamp 5:39), I've also uploaded my file to [blend exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/b/pQZ7RmsW/) if anyone needs to look at the file.

Comment: The link to your Blend file doesn't do anything.

Comment: @JohnEason should be fixed now

Comment: Very strange! It disappears between frame 20 and 21 and there's no sign of any other keyframe or object that could be causing it as far as I can see.

Comment: @JohnEason well thank you for looking at it at least ahah!!

Comment: See my comment to @vklidu's answer which does indeed sort your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch *Timeline* to **Dope Sheet > Grease Pencil** and delete keyframe on frame 21 ...

[image]

Comment: Ah. Yes. Not knowing much about grease pencil, I wondered what the 'Walls' entry was doing in the Outliner. You have to select that before those keyframes appear and you can then delete them.